# Классы. Конструктор. Статические переменные.

Tags: c++

Как создать статическое поле в классе, в котором бы содержалась информация о количестве созданных объектов? Я так думаю, нужно это подсчитывать в конструкторе ? Как это реализовать ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() { ++instanceCounter_; }
    static int instanceCounter() { return instanceCounter_; }
private:
    static int instanceCounter_;
};

#endif
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

int Foo::instanceCounter_ = 0;
```

Comment: что означает эта строчка?
int Foo::instanceCounter_ = 0;

Comment: Инициализация статической переменной instanceCounter_.

Comment: а почему int перед именем класса ?

Comment: это int не перед именем класса, это тип переменной instanceCounter, которая находится в пространстве имен Foo.

Comment: а зачем нщё раз писать int , если это уже определено в самом классе ?

Comment: Такие правила языка

Comment: Защита от повторного включения должна быть в заголовочном файле, а у тебя в Foo.cpp.

Comment: Точно, не туда добавил

Answer (score 1):

Можно и без лишних функций:

Foo.h:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {_count++;}
    const static unsigned int& Count;
private:
    static unsigned int _count;
};
```

Foo.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"
unsigned int Foo::_count=0;
const unsigned int& Foo::Count=Foo::_count;
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << Foo::Count << ", ";
    Foo f1;
    cout << Foo::Count << ", ";
    Foo f2;
    cout << Foo::Count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Выводит "0, 1, 2".

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен паттерн smart pointer.

Comment: Зачем? Вот вопрос.